# Angular Js+Bootstrap+Asp.Net MVC application vertical scrolling is not working in tablet and mobile devices

Tags: css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I have an Angular Js application,In which I am unable to scroll down to the page when opened the application in tablet and mobile device.On desktop it's working as excepted only.
Intial page is _Layout.cshtml:

```
@using System.Web.Optimization
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html @Html.ConditionalManifest()>
<head>
    <meta name="appversion" content="@Helper.ApplicationVersion" />
    <meta name="appmode" content="@(Helper.IsOnline ? "online" : "offline")" />
    <meta name="approot" content="@Url.Content("~/")" />

       <meta charset="utf-8" />
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
       <meta name="description" content="SPA Application" />

       <title>@ViewBag.Title</title>

       @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
       @Styles.Render("~/Content/kendo")
       @RenderSection("Styles", required: false)
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
    </head>
    <body>
<div id="topDiv" ng-app="angAPP" ng-controller="appController">
    <div class="container" id="bodyWrapper">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

                <img src="~/Content/Images/img_logo.gif" class="img-responsive navbar-brand" alt="">
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">

                <img src="~/Content/Images/header.png" class="img-responsive navbar-brand" alt="logo view">
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4" ng-if="!error">
                <div class="navbar-brand" style="float: right; font-size: 12px;">
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>{{userName}}
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>| {{loggedInDate}}
                    <a href="javascript:void(0)"></a>| {{userCompany}}
                </div>
                <div style="float: right;clear: both">
                    <a class="greenText" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-if="!isOnline" title="Sync Status" onmouseover="javascript : $(this).tooltip('show');">
                        <span class="headericons" ng-class="{true: 'processonicon', false: 'processofficon'}[isSyncInProgress]"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="greenText" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Message Information" ng-click="showMessages();" onmouseover="javascript : $(this).tooltip('show');">
                        <span class="headericons mesgicon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="greenText" data-toggle="tooltip" ng-if="!isOnline" title="Sync Online Status" onmouseover="javascript : $(this).tooltip('show');">
                        <span class="headericons" ng-class="{true: 'statusonline', false: 'statusoffline'}[isNetworkAvailable]"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a class="greenText" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Notification" ng-click="showNotifications();" onmouseover="javascript : $(this).tooltip('show');">
                        <span class="headericons notificnicon"></span>
                    </a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signout" ng-click="signOut();" ng-if="isAuthenticated">Sign Out</a>
                    <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="signin" ng-click="signIn();" ng-if="!isAuthenticated">Sign In</a>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
       <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
           <div class="container">
               <div class="navbar-header">
                   <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                       <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                   </button>
                   <a href="#/home" class="navbar-brand">http://blog.longle.net</a>
               </div>
               <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                       <li><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#/customer">Customer</a></li>
                       <li><a href="#/help">API</a></li>
                   </ul>
               </div>
           </div>
       </div>
       <div class="container body-content">
           @RenderBody()
           <footer>
               <p>Copyright &copy; @DateTime.Now.Year - SPA Application</p>
           </footer>
       </div>
     </div>
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/angular")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/app")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/kendo")
       @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/bootstrap")

       @RenderSection("Scripts", required: false)
    </body>
    </html>
```

and Index.cshtml is like this to return the view:

```
  @{
           ViewBag.Title = "SPA";
           ViewBag.Description = "SPA App";
        }
        <div ng-view></div>
```

Overflow-y:scroll/Auto is not helping anything.On page load while page getting loading scroll is working but once all the content and data loaded it's not scrolling.

Could anyone please help me on this.

Thank you,

Comment: Hey amigo, may be you have forgotten to post your code. Would you please post you detail code that you have tried so far?

Comment: @KhalidHussain code is added.